# Decrypt and verify PKCS7 message in C#

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, x509certificate, bouncycastle

I am trying to decrypt and verify PKCS7 response I am getting from client using C#.
Initially I tried Enveloping and signing my payload and followed [the answer mentioned here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916736/openssl-net-porting-a-ruby-example-to-c-sharp-from-railscasts-143-paypal-securi)

Now I am getting response in PKCS7 again and having trouble in Decrypting and verifying the response.

I tried using EnvelopedCMS:

```
        ecms.Decode(Convert.FromBase64String(payloadContent));
        ecms.Decrypt(new X509.X509Certificate2Collection { _signerCert });
        string decodedContent = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ecms.ContentInfo.Content);
```

Here **_signerCert** is my own certificate with private key.

I could see my required response in the **decodedContent** along with some of the client's information and some unknown ASCII characters.
[image: Immediate window reference from Visual studio]

Does anyone know how can I achieve decryption and verification of incoming response?

**Solution found:**

I used SignedCms like this as suggested by @bartonjs

`SignedCms signedCMS = new SignedCms();`

`signedCMS.Decode(ecms.ContentInfo.Content);`

Comment: If you ran it through sign then encrypt when building it, you'd run it through decrypt then verify when receiving it.  Here you've only run it through decrypt.

Comment: What parameters should I use from above to verify it now?

Comment: Assuming you did what the linked post said, now you’d send the content into SignedCms.Decode.

Comment: `SignedCms signedCMS = new SignedCms();`
`signedCMS.Decode(ecms.ContentInfo.Content);`

It worked. Thankyou so much.

Answer (score 1):

```
ICryptoManager objCM = new CryptoManager();

ICryptoContext objContext = objCM.OpenContext( "", true, Missing.Value );

ICryptoMessage objMsg = objContext.CreateMessage( true );

// Obtain encryption certificate
ICryptoCert objCert = objCM.ImportCertFromFile( @"c:\path\mycert.cer" );
objMsg.AddRecipientCert( objCert );


txtResult.Text = objMsg.EncryptText("my secret phrase");
```

Comment: How do it decrypts and verifies the incoming PKCS#7 payload?